# Open the same form twice or more?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm currently working on a game that uses a "simulated operating system". But I'm stuck now. I want the players to be able to open two or more of the same windows, but I just can't get more than one to open. If I want to open another one with the `Form.Show()` command it just doesn't open again.

I would apprechiate any help!

Mika

Comment: dont use the default instance.  `Dim frm As New FormX : frm.Show()` forms are classes (it says so at the top of every one of them) so create objects from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to be offered better help, you should provide the example of the code you are already using (even if it's not working, that's the point).

I'll try to guess what your code is. Since you are mentioning `Form.Show()`, my guess is that your code looks a bit like this:

```
Private formVariable = New FormClass()

Private Sub ButtonClick()
    formVariable.Show()
End Sub
```

If this is the case, what happens is that you created `formVariable` once, and you are calling the same instance over and over again with `formVariable.Show()`.

To solve that, you should create a new instance every time you click the button, like this:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick()
    Dim formVariable = New FormClass()
    formVariable.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Default instances are the devil.

Comment: Sorry for not answering for so long, I got it to work. I did it like that:
`Dim FormToOpen As New FormClass
FormToOpen.Show()`